# Ошибка при поиске контакта с символом апостроф (')

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Приложение для отправки смс. Можно выбрать контакт из телефонной книги и отправить смс. Но если в поле поиска контакта ввести апостроф, то приложение падает с ошибкой android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "'%'": syntax error (code 1).
Буду благодарен всем за помощь. Вот данный метод:

void requestDatabase(String s) {

```
    String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " like'%" + s + "%' " +
            " or " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER + " like'%" + s + "%'";
    String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NAME_RAW_CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI};
    Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY);
    if (cursor != null) {
        List<ContactHintItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            list.add(new ContactHintItem(cursor));
        }
        if (isStringDigit(s))
            list.add(new ContactHintItem(null, s, s, null));
        cursor.close();
        adapter.update(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: попробуйте заменить на двойной апостроф перед записью в бд  replace("'", "''")

Comment: Используйте параметризованные запросы.

Answer (score 1):

У вас одинарный апостроф воспринимается как окончание строки в поисковом запросе. То есть, надо как то поменять апостроф на то, что не разрывает строку. Это называется экранированием.

Экранирование апострофов при вставке или в select-запросе в sqlite делается дублированием этих апострофов:
[ссылка](http://www.prog.org.ru/topic_19545_0.html)

Answer (score 1):

API андройда предлагает использовать [`DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(String value)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils#sqlEscapeString(java.lang.String)) для того чтобы заескейпить все символы, которые необходимо эскейпить в запросах.

Answer (score 1):

Данная проблема была решена!
Можно использовать:

```
if (s.contains("'")) {
   s = s.replaceAll("'", "''");
}
```

Но я не хотел использовать костыль, и искал как правильно параметризировать запрос.
Вот работающий метод с параметрами в запросе:

```
void requestDatabase(String s) {
                String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " like ?" + " or " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER + " like ?";
                String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NAME_RAW_CONTACT_ID,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI};
                Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, new String[]{"%"+s+"%", "%"+s+"%"}, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY);
        
                ...
            }
```